# vagrant/puphpet default: Box 'puphpet/debian75-x64' could not be found

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I am new at Vagrant and I used PuPHPet to build the vagrantfile but when I do the vagrant up command I get this error :

```
λ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'puphpet/debian75-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
The box '["puphpet/debian75-x64"]' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/debian75-x64"]
Error: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Comment: For some reason Vagrant appears to be struggling to follow the certificate chain and doesn't get the intermediate cert. What happens if you go to the URL in your browser? Do you get a fully secure connection? Try checking the certificate information that way.

Comment: Also, what version of Vagrant are you using?

Comment: when i go to the url in my browser, i get nothing the browser load indefinitely, and the version of vagrant i am ising is "Vagrant 1.7.2"
Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an older version of Vagrant then the certificate bundle in the package may be broken. This seems to have been [fixed](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5001#issuecomment-68931516) in 1.7.2
.
If for some reason you have to be pinned to an older version of Vagrant or you're still having issues with an up to date version of Vagrant you can either copy your ca-certificates.crt to Vagrant's cacert.pem with:

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt >> /opt/vagrant/embedded/cacert.pem
```

Or you can tell Vagrant not to worry about the certificate chain being broken by either adding the following line to your [Vagrantfile](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html):

```
config.vm.box_download_insecure = true
```

or by specifying the [`--insecure`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/box.html) option to `vagrant box add` like so:

```
vagrant box add --insecure puphpet/debian75-x64
```